# offline Maps APIs I can use in .NET framework

Tags: raster, c#, .net, software-recommendations, gmap.net

I am trying to find the suitable API where I can:

- load maps from a specific map server (google, openstreetmaps,
  Bing...etc) and use the maps offline.
- loading my own raster layer on top of the original offline map (google, openstreetmaps, Bing...etc)
- adding a customized overlays such as markers, polygons or lines

I tried to use GMap.net it is a great API ,however, I couldn't find a way to load my own raster layer (ecw or geotiff files) 
any other suggestion or API that would serve my need?

Answer (score 2):

You can use DOTSpatial Library as it was one of the Spatial library for .net, check below link for the main website:
https://dotspatial.codeplex.com/